# Вырубается ноутбук на ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

На ноуте стоят две ОС. Первая винда 10. А вторую недавно поставил убунту. Так вот на винде все хорошо, грешить на батарею не получиться. А вот когда загружаю убунту то работать можно разве что только несколько минут, после чего вырубается банально полностью. И такая фигня только тогда когда ноут от батареи работает. Когда подключен к сети все гуд)
Подскажет кто что в убунте надо сделать чтобы это прекратилось? ( на винде же все хорошо с батареей )

Заранее спасибо.
Ps. Нагуглить не получилось(

Comment: А потом перезагружаясь какой заряд батареи остается? Убунта ее садит или нет?

Comment: Показывает приблизительно такой же.. Но чем больше перезагружать тем быстрее начинает вырубаться. Подключаю сеть - все ок. Захожу на винду - все ок

Comment: Она ее все же садит. Вчера не разобрался

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ubuntu садит батарею](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715631/ubuntu-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%8e)

Comment: А зачем же новый вопрос то было создавать раз уже в этом начали разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

1. Думаю что дело в прошивке ноутбука.
   Когда ставил Убунту на свой lenovo g500 обратил внимание,
   что в прошивке стоит тип загружаемой ОС. Windows пользовался
   достаточно долго, но там другие ОС подгружал через виртуальную машину.
   В этом случае проблем и быть не могло))
2. Вариант отключения Убунту. Версия 18.04.3 по умолчанию засыпает через 5 минут.
   Это время в настройках можно изменить. Существует даже вариант установки специальной утилиты Caffeine, предотвращающей засыпание Ubuntu. Юмор,однако у разработчиков - хорошее название придумали для данной утилиты))