# Ubuntu садит батарею

Tags: ubuntu

На ноуте стоят две ОС. Первая винда 10. А вторую недавно поставил убунту. Так вот на винде все хорошо, грешить на батарею не получиться. А вот когда загружаю убунту то работать можно разве что только несколько минут, после чего вырубается ноут. И такая фигня только тогда когда ноут от батареи работает. Когда подключен к сети проблем нет и на винде проблем тоже нет. Подскажет кто что в убунте надо сделать чтобы она прекратила сажать батарею так быстро? ( на винде же все хорошо с ней)

Заранее спасибо. Ps. Нагуглить толком ничего не получилось(

Comment: askubuntu.com добро пожаловать

Answer (score 1):

есть прекрасная утилита powertop она подскажет откуда именно, данная проблема. 
Так же ознакомьтесь [Пост о оптимизации](https://habrahabr.ru/post/115451/)

Comment: Спасибо скачаю. Но тут такое дело. На винде может полтора часа вытянуть. А на убунте 5-10 мин... Это как то уж очень мало и дело врядли в одной оптимизации

Comment: случаем не две видеокарты в ноуте?

Comment: две. Как раз почитал что одна слабее а другая сильная. Походу на винде все норм. А на убунте работает сильная чтоли и садит за 10мин

Comment: А в батарее ли проблема? А вы логи смоотрели? Какая Ubuntu, модель ноута...

Comment: отключил на убунте нвидию и все стало норм

Comment: статья помогла?